# mysql search for 'No.' not 'no.' or 'no';

Tags: mysql, case-sensitive

Is there any way that  i can cause mysql to be case sensitive whe searching using where x like '%No.%';

Comment: Don't use an initial wildcard with like queries.  It breaks indexing.  Use a fulltext index instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <column> COLLATE latin1_bin LIKE '%No.%'
```

Comment: +1: Beat me, here's a supporting link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html  Collations with "ci" are case insensitive, while "cs" means case sensitive...

Answer (score 3):

You could change the column type:

```
create table my_table (case_sensitive_column VARCHAR(10)) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin;
```

**EDIT**
Actually, **jwsample**'s answer is better because you don't have to modify the table.

Comment: Unless you always do it, then yours is better ;-)

Answer (score 0):

http://web.archive.org/web/20080811231016/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-can-i-make-my-sql-queries-case-sensitive.html

http://aspadvice.com/blogs/ssmith/archive/2007/09/30/Case-Sensitive-or-Insensitive-SQL-Query.aspx

Comment: Answering the question is typically better than providing a link that might be dead in 5 years when someone else finds this question.

Comment: But he's using mysql, not SQL Server.

Comment: The link could be dead tomorrow.

Comment: MySQL is already 15 years old.  Why wouldn't this question be relevant in 5 years.